# Calling webservice in C# returns Client found response content type of '', but expected 'text/xml'

Tags: c#, soap, coldfusion

I am currently calling a ColdFusion web service in C#.  The web service is just a simple query used to search for users.  I can search just fine and it returns the users I search for unless I try searching for 'Johnson' then it returns:

```
Client found response content type of '', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:
--

--.
```

I don't know why it doesn't work when searching for that specific string.  I thought it might be timing out but the error pops up immediately after sending the request.  Any ideas???

Comment: Is there any additional information? I know i have seen a similar message but it says something like "Client found response content type of 'text/html'...". This just means that service sent back the error in html and you can usually see what the problem was. You could always run Fiddler to see the actual request and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, turns out there was an invalid character being returned in one of the rows in the query that couldn't be put in the xml.  Removed the invalid character and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

may be output is corrupt. try network analyzer WireShark to see what's going on behind the scene.

Comment: .net should throw more relevant exception, because 500 means error. i think something went wrong on server side, check it

Comment: As Andrey states, 500 errors are uncaught exceptions.  Basically, something went wrong (JRun crashed, syntax error, whatever) and the server stack doesn't know how to cleanly handle the error.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by calling the service manually, and seeing what the raw return value is.  Is it throuwing an error?  Returning null?  Some third option?

Comment: If I call the function in the web browser, it returns just fine.  I just monitored the response in WireShark and I see a server 500 error.  Why would that happen?

Comment: Server 500 is some sort of error happening in ColdFusion. Check the ColdFusion logs.

Comment: I found the problem in the ColdFusion logs, turns out there was an invalid character that was trying to be returned.  I removed the character from the users name and it works fine now.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. Can it be that this specific query has no matches found, so web-service returns the non-XML result (empty sting in your case)? Does this happen when you ask any other non-existing name (some "blah-blah-blah")? If this is correct, it's definitely a logical bug in service code.